# PowerBI blank data template

Tags: mdx, powerbi

Currently I'm working on a dashboard template in PowerBI that will be piloted in the desktop version. The template is filled with data based on the user's authorization through a filter applied within the MDX query. However when spreading the template to others for piloting, it is still filled with data based on my personal authorizations which is only replaced as soon as the user refreshes using his personal authorizations.

**I'm looking for a solution** that does not break the template but also makes sure that my data is not shown to others when opening the template, in other words how can I make sure the user sees an empty template (no data) when opening the file.

I've tried blanking the filter parameter (results in data errors and missing columns thus breaking the dashboard)

Can anyone help me find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. I've managed to solve the problem with a simple solution. By adding a try structure around the Table.RenameColumns function after the MDX I was able to capture a blank query and use Table.FromRecords to manually add the otherwise retrieved columns with a blank row. This prevents all subsequent queries and measures from returning errors and thus blanking all figures when the user parameter is invalid. Then finally just add any invalid value to the user parameter and save as a template, voila.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a template user (just for report creation) and set the **Scope** statement around your measures:

```
Scope(AddCalculatedMembers([Measures].Members));
    This = IIF(
                [Measures].CurrentMember
                and
                UserName() == "domain\template.user",
                "Blank",
                NULL
    );
End Scope;
```

Comment: to me it sounds like cube security is already in place Danylo - the question is more in respect of the PowerBI template caching results which are then visible to subsequent users - how does the questioner still allow the user access to the template but ensure that no previous rerults are cached within the template?

Comment: If template.user shares a report, measure values will be blanked and initially cached as blanked. You may apply the same for dimension members, probably (never tried though). If non-template.user will reshare the report, yeah, there is no security guarantee. From Excel retrospection this user can be used only at template preparing (I'll blog about it later). Not sure about Power BI, because it still is being developed and pre-caching is a prior feature itself.